# Uploaded android app in google play showing no device

Tags: android

I have uploaded an android app created in cordova into google play...
After upload it is showing zero supplorted device...
Here is my manifest file. I do not know what to do. Please help.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest 
android:versionCode="7" 
android:versionName="7.0.0" 
package="com.xiphos.nabc.cordova" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-sdk 
android:minSdkVersion="9" 
android:targetSdkVersion="20" 
android:maxSdkVersion="20" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application
android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:allowBackup="false" >
<activity
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" 
android:label="@string/activity_name" 
android:launchMode="singleTop" 
android:name=".CordovaApp" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" 
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
   <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
    <service android:name=".NotificationService" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

SDK 20 was the L preview, you cannot use that for a production app. Change it to 21.

https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html

Comment: I have changed it to 21 but it is still showing the same.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change `android:targetSdkVersion="20"` to a lower value such as `android:targetSdkVersion="14"`. Hope it helps.